# Decoding seems to have no effect in Python socket script

Tags: python, arrays, sockets, amazon-ec2, encoding

I am attempting to communicate between two AWS EC2 instances using Python sockets.

The code is as follows:

```
sQuery.connect((hostIP, port))
inpString = str(inpString)
inpString = inpString.encode('utf-8')
sQuery.sendall(inpString)
```

which was, before

```
sQuery.connect((hostIP, port))

sQuery.sendall(inpString).encode('utf-8')
```

and it worked fine, till one test run when the machine decided it needed a bytes object not string. So I changed it to the explicit version above. The code iterates through this for every IP address in a list (connecting to one, doing some stuff, then disconnecting then connecting to next). If I do not keep the
`inpString = str(inpString)` then the first iteration goes fine but the second one it says bytes has no attribute 'encode'.

The problem is on the other end of the socket, which runs this code:

```
searchTerm = (conn.recv(2048))
print(type(searchTerm))
searchTerm = searchTerm.decode('utf-8')
print(type(searchTerm))
print('Data received: ', searchTerm)
```

to get the following output:

```
Listening on  <Listening PORT>
Connected by  ('IP ADDRESS', PORT)
<class 'bytes'> #received data
<class 'str'> #after performing the explicit decode above 
Data received:  b'yard' #AND YET IT SHOWS A BYTE OBJECT
```

As you can see, even after the type of object is str (string), the Data received: print statement shows a byte object!
Then when I use the 'data received' term, in this case "b'yard'" while searching through a text file it says nothing found, since it is a byte object not a string. But I do not know what I am doing wrong with the data type changes? I explicitly change it to string, and Python agrees, but when using the decoded string, it shows up as a byte object!

EDIT: Steffen Ullrich's answer below made sense and it worked!

TO answer his question, I changed this code:

```
sQuery.connect((hostIP, port))
inpString = str(inpString)
inpString = inpString.encode('utf-8')
sQuery.sendall(inpString)
```

to this:

```
sQuery.connect((hostIP, port))

try:
    inpString = inpString.encode('utf-8')
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

My reasoning was: if on the second iteration the code encounter inpString to be bytes, and would like to throw "Bytes object has no attribute encode", this should take care of it.

Comment: This requires some more investigation. If you hard-code `searchTerm = b'yard'` everything seems to work fine. The problem may be in the nature of `searchTerm`. What type of byte object is it? Can it be decoded with 'utf-8' or should you use something else to convert it from bytes to string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with sockets. You simply sent the wrong string from start and you don't recover from this mistake in the recipient.

> ```
> inpString = str(inpString)
> ```

You have the wrong assumption that `str(...)` converts bytes to a string. But it does not, at least not in the way you want. It does not treat the bytes as characters but it converts it only into a readable representation which still shows that this was bytes:

```
$ python3
...
>>> b=b'1234'
>>> len(b)
4
>>> s=str(b)
>>> s
"b'1234'"
>>> len(s)
7
```

As you can see it converts the bytes sequence `b'1234'` (length 4) into the string `"b'1234'"` (length 7). Instead of using `str` you should treat the bytes  as sequence of characters and `decode` it into a string:

```
>>> s=b.decode('utf-8')
>>> s
'1234'
>>> len(s)
4
```

Comment: Oof! Thanks a lot for the explanation. I got frustrated and started banging stuff out. I have also added
```
try:
    inpString = inpString.encode('utf-8')
except AttributeError:
    pass
```
So in the second iteration when it usually would give me AttributeError: Byte object has no attribute encode, it is ignored. That makes sense right?

Comment: @SohumBilawalNikhilJoshi: " That makes sense right?"* - I don't have enough context to decide if this makes sense.  It is not clear for me what you were trying to achieve with this and where in your code you've used it.